# How can I use condition to decide the output binding should exist or not?

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

Refer picture above.

I called app-row-toolbar component from lines 129 to 135. However, I have three input variables at the `MainComponent` are `isConfig`, `isEdit`, `isDelete` corresponding with three output variables `onConfig`, `onEdit`, `onDelete`.

#### Assumption

Only input variable `isEdit` is true and `isConfig` & `isDelete` are false. How can I use condition to hide others output `onConfig` and `onDelete`

#### Example

I did use `(onConfig)="isConfig ? handleConfig(item) : null"` but it didn't work.

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why it's not working? How about `(onConfig)="isConfig && handleConfig(item)"`

Comment: What I expect is to make the (onConfig) gone when  config is false

Comment: Well does the above work for you? Also please post code, not screenshots of code whenever possible.

Comment: app-row-toolbar component should have an input property called `configAction` or something like that to make `config` functionality visible or not.